# DNS point to internal IP

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I have a DNS entry for an IP which can be accessed externally it is http://xyz.abc.com. I have set it up and it is working

Now I also have a 123.abc.loc which is attached to an IP internally on 192.168.23.105. I want this 123.abc.loc to be accessed externally. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: It really depends of your network architecture. Do you have spare public IP addresses, do you need to access specific ports or maybe you need all port to be exposed to Internet ?

Comment: No, I do not have a spare public IP and if needed I can open one port @mrc02_kr

Comment: If you want to expose an internal http service to the internet you need to set up a reverse proxy. Please search for the term and learn how it can be applied to your task, a complete explanation of how to set up a reverse proxy is beyond the scope of a comment or even an answer here as much more info about your requirements would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

A loc DNS domain address is an internal DNS view with a name created at random, and is not meant to be accessed directly in the Internet at least.

Only your internal infra-structure/internal DNS view has the visibility for the loc DNS domain.

If you need to access externally *as it is*, the best option is to setup a VPN for your internal network infra-structure.

You may also setup a reverse authenticated HTTP/Socks proxy to your internal intra-structure, however from the security point of view, it is not such a good idea. Go with the VPN.

You can also setup up a new URL in your already existent vhost, or associate your name with that public IP, and do proxing for the internal website.